# How can I handle selected check box items in php

Tags: php, html

I have this form I can't figure it out how can I display my selected check box item name in the result. On my html site I am using  value to calculate total price but when it comes to show what has been selected in the result it shows the value of the selected item. How can handle this in php? This is my result and I will post my code as well.

---

Your name is:              Jim 
Your total cost is:        4.56 
Your payment method is:    Visa 
Your Selected Product(s):  4.29

---

Here at the last part  I need show selected products name not the value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Light Bulbs Sales Form </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2> Welcome to Light Bulbs Sales Form </h2>
    <form action="php/index.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label> Buyer's Name:
                <input type="text" name="name" size="30" /> 
            </label>
        <p/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="2.39" /></td>
                <td> Four 25-watt light bulbs </td>
                <td> $2.39 </td>                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="4.29"/></td>
                <td> Eight 25-watt light bulbs </td>
                <td> $4.29 </td>                       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="3.95"/></td>
                <td> Four 25-watt long-life light bulbs </td>
                <td> $3.95 </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="7.49"/></td>
                <td> Eight 25-watt long-life light bulbs </td>
                <td> $7.49 </td>     
            </tr>
        </table>  
        <h3>Payment Method</h3>
            <p>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Visa"/>Visa</label>
                <br/>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Master Card"/>Master Card</label>
                <br/>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Discover"/>Discover</label>
                <br/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Clear Order Form"/>
            </p>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$bulbs=$_POST["b"];
$pmode=$_POST["payment"];

$select_val=$_POST["b"];

$total=0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($bulbs);$i++)
{
    $tax=$bulbs[$i]*0.062;
    $total=$total+$bulbs[$i]+$tax;
    $totalcost=number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');
}

print "Your name is: $name <br>";
print "Your total cost is: $totalcost <br>";
print "Your payment method is: $pmode <br>";

print "Your Selected Product(s):<br>";

for ($j=0; $j <count($select_val) ; $j++) { 
    
$select_val[$j]."<br>";
    
    echo $select_val[$j]  ;
 
}       

?>
```

Comment: The names aren't in $_POST because they're just in <td> tags and not in an element that gets sent in $_POST.  You could use JavaScript / JQuery to populate a hidden input when an item is selected.  There are other ways to handle this, too.  But the end result is that you need to put those names into an element that's sent in $_POST.

Comment: on same page are submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

As Devlin stated as a comment, the product names aren't being submitted with the form because they are just plain text on the page.  The text just happens to be next to the buttons.

There are a few solutions to this that I can think of off the top of my head.

---

### Solution 1: Associative array

Instead having the price in the value of the checkbox, you could have the name of the product, like `<input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="Four 25-watt light bulbs" />`.  You would then have an array in the PHP script that an associative array with the titles of the product and their respective prices, like so:

```
$products = array(
    "Four 25-watt light bulbs" => 2.39,
    "Eight 25-watt light bulbs" => 4.29,
    "Four 25-watt long-life light bulbs" => 3.95,
    "Eight 25-watt long-life light bulbs" => 7.49
);
```

Instead of just accessing the price for the bulbs with `$bulbs[$i]`, you would then instead do it with `$products[$bulbs[$i]]`.

And of course, you couldn't have it flipped where the checkbox still sends the price because some products could have the same price.

---

### Solution 2: Javascript

You could have there be an hidden input next to each checkbox which submits the name of the product using Javascript.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bulbs[]" value="2.39" onchange="onChange(this)"/><input type="hidden" name="" value="">
```

My Javascript skills are pretty much non-existent, so getting a working example was out of my reach, but the basic gist of it is that you'd want to find the next sibling of the checkbox and then set its name to `products[]` and its value to the correct name of the product its associated with.

---

### Solution 3: Product IDs

The final solution is to assign each product a product ID.  I would recommend this one as it's the easiest to expand and the easiest to maintain.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bulbs[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="bulbs[]" value="2"/>
...etc...
```

In your PHP script you'd have a multi-dimensional associative array like this:

```
$products = array(
    1 => array("name" => "Four 25-watt light bulbs",
                "price" => 2.39),
    2 => array("name" => "Eight 25-watt light bulbs",
                "price" => 4.29),
    3 => array("name" => "Four 25-watt long-life light bulbs",
                "price" => 3.95),
    4 => array("name" => "Eight 25-watt long-life light bulbs",
                "price" => 7.49)
);
```

You would then access the price and the name not with `$bulbs[$i]`, but with `$products[$bulbs[$i]]["price"]` or `$products[$bulbs[$i]]["name"]`.